# How does Ctrl+B keyboard binding works?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-hook

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in `Word` and other shortcuts work the same no matter what language I'm using - how is this binding done? Can it be done in Java?

Comment: Because bindings are done on keys not on writing languages. It doesn't mean B word it means B key on keyboard.

Comment: Actually, they are not always the same. On swedish word installations Ctrl-B is find...

Comment: @Harry, Can you elaborate please? Is it done via Assembly code?

Comment: What effect are you talking about? What does the key combination do in Word?

Comment: @Hovercraft: I think OP is talking about making a text **bold** in MS Word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I wonder that typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> creates different key code when you are using different languages? In this case look into KeyEvent API. It has 2 relevant methods: getKeyCode() and getKeyChar().

getKeyChar() invoked when key is down depends on current language. getKeyCode() does not depend. It always return the code of the key, not the letter associated with it. Moreover I found that (at least on my system - Linux Fedora) getkeyChar() invoked on key released returns the English character even when current language is different.

Here are the results of pressing and releasing of the same key with 3 different input languages installed on my system: English, Russian and Hebrew.

pressed: ф 65
released: a 65
pressed: a 65
released: a 65
pressed: ש 65
released: a 65

As you can see the key code is always the same although the char is different.

Comment: So `getKeyCode()` returns the ASCII code of the English character (in Uppercase)?

Answer (score 1):

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for an explanation of how this works in Swing.